# Implicit differentiation of $f(x)g(y) = 2x + \ln(y) − 5$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I am unsure how to solve this problem.

> Find $$\frac{dy}{dx} f(x)g(y) = 2x + \ln(y) − 5$$
> where $f$ is a differentiable function of $x$ and $g$ is a differentiable function of $y$.

I know to use implicit differentiation, however, I get this:
$$f'(x)g(y) + f(x)g'(y) = 2 + \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}$$
and am not sure where to go from here.

I will appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: Implicit differentiation  is used when you have something like $F(x,y)=c$, a constant.  That's not what you have.   Note too that there are no functions $f,g$ that satisfy your claim for all real $x$ and $y>0$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you! Does that mean it is impossible to differentiate? Is there any other way?

Comment: Not following.  Again, there are no two functions that satisfy your condition so there is nothing to differentiate.

Comment: Hm, okay thank you. There seems to be an error with the question then.